# Using ratios n Excell without reducing

Tags: excellibrary

Is it possible to convert A and B to ratio in excel, but not reduce it? It is for a employee to kids ratio in a daycare. 12 kids and 3 kids would be entered 12 in A and 3 in B to show 12:3. I just don't want it reduced to 4:1, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have 12 in one cell, and 3 in another, and wish to display them in a third cell as a ratio: 12:3.

In that case, this is how it's done:
Say you have the 12 in cell A1 and the 3 in cell B1, and you wish to display the ratio in cell C1. To do this, click on cell C1, and type in the following formula in the formula bar:

```
    =A1&":"&B1
```

This instructs Excel to combine the contents of A1, a colon in double quotes, and the contents of cell B1, into cell C1.

Bilal